# radio button is changing size following zoom in or out on firefox

Tags: html, forms, firefox, radio-button

I have this situation where radio buttons on my HTML page changing sizes following zoom in or zoom out on firefox only (not happening in chrome).

When my page is in his default size (100%) it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRYRa.png)

When my page is in size 100% ++  the radio buttons getting smaller like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlgNk.png)

When my page is in size 100% --  the radio buttons getting bigger like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjllG.png)

**HTML:**

```
 <span class="value"><span class="" style=""><input type="radio"  name="80" id="radio80~1" value="1" onchange=""><label class="inline"  for="80">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></span><span class="" style=""><input type="radio"  name="80" id="radio80~2" value="2" onchange=""><label class="inline" for="80">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></span><span class="" style=""><input type="radio"  name="80" id="radio80~3" value="3" onchange=""><label class="inline" for="80">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></span><span class="" style=""><input type="radio"  name="80" id="radio80~4" value="4" onchange=""><label class="inline" for="80">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></span></span><span class="" style=""><input type="radio"  name="80"id="radio80~5" value="5" onchange=""><label class="inline" for="80">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></span></span><span class="" style=""><input type="radio"  name="80"id="radio80~6" value="6" onchange=""><label class="inline" for="80">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></span></span><span class="" style=""><input type="radio"  name="80" id="radio80~7" value="7" onchange=""><label class="inline" for="80">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</label></span></span>
```

how can i make it one size and not depend on the web size?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your HTML looks a bit like a mess.
I have tried to make it a little bit better to read, see:

```
  <div class="input-value">
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="80" id="radio80~1" value="1">
      <label class="inline" for="80">&bnsp;</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="80" id="radio80~2" value="2">
      <label class="inline" for="80">&bnsp;</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="80" id="radio80~3" value="3">
      <label class="inline" for="80">&bnsp;</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="80" id="radio80~4" value="4">
      <label class="inline" for="80">&bnsp;</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="80" id="radio80~5" value="5">
      <label class="inline" for="80">&bnsp;</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="80" id="radio80~6" value="6">
      <label class="inline" for="80">&bnsp;</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="80" id="radio80~7" value="7">
      <label class="inline" for="80">&bnsp;</label>
    </span>
  </div>
```

The zooming issue could be that the inputs have custom CSS applied?
If so, can you provide this? I think it has to do with the height and width set in pixels and can't calculate right when zooming in and out. You could try set the width and height in REM value's like this:

```
  .input-value input {
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
  }
```

See also: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/